# ASP.NET MVC4 ViewModel and knockoutJS ViewModel repetition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have an MVC4 application with a Model (Entity) DLL project that is used in the BusinessLogic and DataAccess layers. The MVC Controllers convert the ViewModels (bound to the Views) to the Models using some mapper extension methods and pass the Model objects to the BusinessLogic layer.

My question is: If I need some client-side features like KnockoutJS, is it good practice to create a further set of KnockoutJS ViewModels? I am concerned about maintainability and frequent changes in the ViewModels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say no, knockoutJS is a *client-side* library and therefore shouldn't really dictate how your server sends down data. As long as your view models contain all the relevant information required to render then that's all you need. How the client then handles that is completely irrelevant to the server.

By creating knockoutJS specific view models your essentially coupling your server responses to your client which is not a good idea - what if down the line you changed to a different client? What if you want to support multiple clients?

I would recommend creating a client-side representation of your view model which is specific to KnockoutJS instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you create ViewModels specific to KnockoutJS (or for any other client to consume).

I feel that ViewModels that are used within your site, on the server-side, should be able to easily change because the site is both creating them and consuming them. Besides, you have the compiler to let you know if something is not correct.

However, I feel that when we expose these models to a client, these become a bit more of a contract which should not change, or at the very least, not change that often.

Comment: "*I would recommend you create a ViewModel specific to KnockoutJS (or for any other client to consume)*" - I disagree, the server shouldn't be worried about *how* a client is going to render the data it sends down, it's job is to ensure it *sends* the data. Creating a separate view model for various clients is a terrible idea IMO. A single view model should suffice for *all* clients.

Comment: Yes, what I meant by "or for any other client to consume" is that a separate view model should be created for _any_ client to consume. I did not mean that a different view model should be created for each and every client.